# How do I get an array of times with a start hour, end hour, and duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to come up with a way to get an array of times based on it's start hour, end hour, and duration in minutes.

For example:
Start Hour: 9
End Hour: 17
Duration: 15

I successfully have done this by looping over the start and end hour and then have a loop inside that loop to calculate the minutes.

```
function getTimesArray(start, end, length) {
    var time_array = [];
    var duration = length / 60;
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = start, len = end; i < len; i++) {
        var minutes = 1 / duration;
        for (var b = 0, leng = minutes; b < leng; b++) {
            var min = length * b;
            time_array[count] = i + ':' + (min == 0 ? "00" : min);

            count ++;
        }
    }

    time_array[time_array.length+1] = i + ':' + "00";

    return time_array;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvtpqx8c/

The issue with this is that you can only put in a duration of 60 minutes max because it always loops over the hours.

What I need is to be able to calculate the times no matter how many minutes the length is. For example, if the length is 120, it should show every 2 hours from start to end hours.

Comment: It's not quite clear what is length and why you divide it by 60

Comment: what should the output of `getTimesArray(1,2, 45)` be?

Comment: @Banzay the length is the duration in minutes of each hour. So it's basically time slots. A business is open from hour start to hour end and I need an array of times in between based on the duration in minutes. Check out the fiddle for clarity

Comment: @MarkMeyer [1], since the next time won't be available

Comment: @fyroc not `[1:00, 1:45]` ??

Comment: @MarkMeyer no because 2 is closing time, however, thinking about it, 1:45 should be added and the user will just need to. know that the end time is the last appointment that CAN be created, not the time the business closes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6v8hbd7f/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a bit easier if you think of everything in terms of minutes and calculate the hours:minutes when you make the string. This will let you use a simple `while` loop rather than a complicated `for` loop with conditions. Then you can just add the minutes to the start time and end when it's greater or equal to the end time:

```js
function getTimesArray(start, end, length) {
    let startMin = start * 60
    let endMin = end * 60
    let times = []

    while (startMin <= endMin){
        let mins = startMin % 60
        let hours = Math.floor(startMin / 60)
        let timeString = hours.toString() + ":" +  mins.toString().padStart(2, '0')
        times.push(timeString)
        startMin += length
    }
    return times
}
console.log(getTimesArray(1,6, 12))
console.log(getTimesArray(4,8, 110))
```

This doesn't include the end if the duration overshoots it as in the second example above as this would add a duration different than length. It would be a simple thing to push one more time on if you need that, however.